# GNU Arm warning:-mcpu=cortex-r5 conflicts with -march=armv7-r switch

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-r

I get the following warning:

```
-mcpu=cortex-r5 conflicts with -march=armv7-r switch
```

When I set -mcpu to cortex-r4 or cortex-r4f I do not get the problem. As the Cortex R5 is the same armv7-r architecture I am assuming this is a bug in the GCC toolchain? I am currently using the Arm Launchpad 5.4 2016q3 tools.

I am also wondering why there is not a Cortex-r5f option as the floating point unit is optional.

I am guessing that the `-mcpu` options does not really make a lot of difference?

Comment: Don't use `-mcpu`, use `-mtune`.  The `-mcpu` and `-march` are in conflict with each others; they never make sense together.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I have done and it seems to work fine. I was using --mcpu=cortex-4f with -march=armv7-r ok though. Looking at the docs  I think perhaps you do not need to use -mtune or -march if you use -mcpu as it should derive it.

Comment: I am writing deeply embedded code for specific hardware so -mcpu could be applicable. If we were to run the code on other hardware it would definitely need to be rebuilt. However I agree -march and -mtune seem to be the way to go. If I get time I will try and see if it makes any difference to the compiled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am guessing that the `-mcpu` options does not really make a lot of difference?

Yes, this is more than correct.  The `-mcpu` option superseded the `-march`; it is more specific.  For the *cortex-r4*, it is a minimal cortex-r system, so it is basically the synonymous with `-march=armv7-r`.  You can idealize  at `-mcpu=xxx` as both `-march=xxx` and `-mtune=xxx`.  There are some systems where 'x' and 'y' may each have unique features. But the for cortex-r, the cortex-r4 is the minimum.  This explains observed (correct) behaviour.

Even in present day, the error still pesists.

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (15:10.3-2021.07-4) 10.3.1 20210621 (release)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cat test.c
/*@ 
   ensures \result >= 0;
   ensures x < 0 ==> \result == -x;
   ensures x >= 0 ==> \result == x;
 */
int abs(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        return -x;
    else
        return x;
}
 
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -mcpu=cortex-r5 -march=armv7-r -O3 -c -o test.o test.c
cc1: warning: switch '-mcpu=cortex-r5' conflicts with '-march=armv7-r' switch
```

As I said in the comments, the correct option is `-mtune`.

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -mtune=cortex-r5 -march=armv7-r -O3 -c -o test.o test.c
```

Here you generate code for any cortex-r system, but it will be optimized for a cortex-r5.  If you really want to target only the cortex-r5, then use **ONLY** the `-mcpu=cortex-r5` option.  The code will be slightly better.  However, often you use 3rd party libraries and sometimes they are closed source and compiled with some other flags (many question here on SO on this topic). Using `-march` will also allow you more possibilities to use 3rd party closed source as well.

You should be able to link `-mcpu=cortex-r5` with `-march=armv7-r` code; well it is fine in one directions, so the tools may complain.  You could get around this... but that is not the question.