# What is the purpose of the gcc ARM-option -mlibarch?

Tags: arm, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I took over a project started from a colleague of mine and now I'm trying to understand what he did so far.

Aim of the project is run a Profinet device on a NetX90 (2x Cortex M4).
The IDE used so for is the netX studio 1.1010.1.5895 on Win10 machine.

While I was examining the CMakeOutput.log file I read the compiler options `... -mlibarch=armv4t -march=armv4t ...`.

And I wondered what -mlibarch is used for if -march is already set.
With the source my colleague left the binary is build so I thing the option is recognized by the compiler but I don't find the documentation for that flag.

I search online for the flag in

1. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html
2. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/gcc/ARM-Options.html
3. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html
4. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/gcc-command-options/options-for-linking.html#cmdoption-nostdlib
5. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html#Option-Index_op_letter-O

I  tried in the terminal the help of

1. arm-none-eabi-cpp.exe,
2. arm-none-eabi-gcc-11.2.1.exe and
3. arm-none-eabi-ld.exe

(I know the last one is the linker but the name "mlibarch" sounds for me like linker stuff)

Does anybody know better? Maybe with a link to an explanation.

Thank in advance.

Regards,

Layer8

Comment: I think it is an option for 'multi-lib', giving the name of the directory where to search for the architectures library.  It is equivalent to a `-L`, but may look for spec files or something else in the directory as well.  Also, given you have a Cortex-M4, this is not an optimal arch at all.  I would pick `-march=armv7-m` at least. See: [Cortex-R cpu, tune, arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934764/gnu-arm-warning-mcpu-cortex-r5-conflicts-with-march-armv7-r-switch).  This seems like someone thought 'v4' was equivalent to m4.  But also, that doesn't have thumb2 ISA (arch of armv4).

Comment: So, the bigger question is, is any of this correct for your system?  It  looks like you are using the **MOST** basic thumb ISA possible, restricting to 8 registers.  Change it to `-march=armv7-m`  or `-mcpu=cortex-m4` and you can look brilliant.  Step 1, understand your hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your help. "Step 1, understand your hardware" is what I'm doing now. Or better: "Understand how the hardware is used" is what I try to do, that why I looked for the compiler and linker flags.

If I find a document for the option I'll link it here. 

Thank you so far.